# Moment Arm: What dia.(3" or 4") Alum pole 10ft long (thickness .125) will support a load 200 or 300lb pulling at 90 degrees at the end of the pole?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, beam

I am trying to determine which diameter (3" or 4") metal pole I need to support a 20ft x 20ft pool shade tarp.  I can use either steel or aluminum (aluminum preferred).  The wall thickness will be at least .125 (gauge 11).  Pole will be a total of 12ft in length with 10ft being the moment arm and 2ft in the ground.  I am assuming a load of 200 - 300lbs acting on the arm at the end of the 10ft length.
In summary: Would an aluminum pole 10 ft long (moment arm) with a 3" diameter with a .125 thickness support a load of 200lbs?  300lbs? or  Do I need to go to a 4" diameter pole to support 200lbs or 300lbs?

Answer (score 1):

Circular beam I ,

$I_{xx}=\pi/4(R^4-R_i^4)\rightarrow I_x= 1.1687in^4$

$M=300*10=3000 ft.lbs$

We use 2.5 as factor of safety due to dynamic gust loading.

M=3000*2.5=7500lbs.ft

$\sigma= My/I<25000 alum= (7500*1.5*12)/1.1687=115512.9psi $

We are by far underdesigned.

testing for a 4in pipe. $1155512.9*3/4^2=64976.04psi>25000$ no good.

It would be better if you can tie the post to get rid of the moment.

Comment: I got exactly the same numbers. Despite the fact that you are using the dynamic safety factor, the assumption of 300lbs seems a bit low to me.